# How to run jobs in paralell using one slurm batch script?

Tags: parallel-processing, slurm

I am trying to run multiple python scripts in parallel with one Slurm batch script. Take a look at the example below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --output=/dev/null
#SBATCH --error=/dev/null
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1G
#SBATCH --partition=All
#SBATCH --time=5:00

srun sleep 60
srun sleep 60
wait
```

How do I tweak the script such that the execution will take only 60 sec (instead of 120) ? Splitting the script into two scripts is not an option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As written, that script is running two `sleep` commands **in parallel**, **two times in  a row**.

Each `srun` command initiates a *step*, and since you set `--ntasks=2` each step instantiates two *tasks* (here the `sleep` command).

If you want to run two 1-task steps in parallel, you should write it this way:

```
srun --exclusive -n 1 -c 1 sleep 60 &
srun --exclusive -n 1 -c 1 sleep 60 &
wait
```

Then each step only instantiates one task, and is backgrounded by the `&` delimiter, meaning the next `srun` can start immediately. The `wait` command makes sure the script terminates only when both steps are finished.

**In that context,** the [xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) command and the [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) commands can be useful to avoid writing multiple identical `srun` lines or avoiding a `for-`loop.

For instance, if you have multiple files you need to run your script over:

```
find /path/to/data/*.csv -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P $SLURM_NTASKS srun -n1 --exclusive python my_python_script.py
```

This is equivalent to writing as many

```
srun -n 1 -c 1 --exclusive python my_python_script.py /path/to/data/file1.csv &
srun -n 1 -c 1 --exclusive python my_python_script.py /path/to/data/file1.csv &
srun -n 1 -c 1 --exclusive python my_python_script.py /path/to/data/file1.csv &
[...]
```

GNU parallel is useful to iterate over parameter values:

```
parallel -P $SLURM_NTASKS srun  -n1 --exclusive python my_python_script.py ::: {1..1000}
```

will run

```
python my_python_script.py 1
python my_python_script.py 2
python my_python_script.py 3
...
python my_python_script.py 1000
```

**Another approach** is to just run

```
srun python my_python_script.py
```

and, inside the Python script, to look for the `SLURM_PROCID` environment variable and split the work according to its value. The `srun` command will start multiple instances of the script and each will 'see' a different value for `SLURM_PROCID`.

```
import os
print(os.environ['SLURM_PROCID'])
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is super valuable and helps me understand Slurm better. However, I do not understand the keyword --exclusive. I do not need an entire node. I just want the script [ here a sleep] to be execute. That can be done on the same Node.

Comment: It is counterintuitive, but the `--exclusive` keyword has a different meaning in this context; it is used precisely to 'split' the allocation in sub-steps. See the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html#OPT_exclusive[=user|mcs]) for details. In recent versions of Slurm this is actually the default.

Comment: Could you expand on the last option? How to "split the work according to its value"? How many instances of the script will be started?

Comment: in the code of the program called by `srun`, use the value of `SLURM_PROCID` to run for instance a subset of a loop `for i = SLURM_PROCID to SLURM_PROCID + 20`. the number of instances will be the number set with `--ntasks`