# What does the keyword --exclusive mean in slurm?

Tags: parallel-processing, slurm

This is a follow up question from [[How to run jobs in paralell using one slurm batch script?]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66805098/how-to-run-jobs-in-paralell-using-one-slurm-batch-script). The goal was to create a single SBatch-Script, which can start multiple processes and run them in parallel. The Answer given by
**damienfrancois** was very detailed and looked something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --output=/dev/null
#SBATCH --error=/dev/null
#SBATCH --partition=All

srun -n 1 -c 1 --exclusive sleep 60 &
srun -n 1 -c 1 --exclusive sleep 60 &
....
wait
```

However, I am not able to understand the **exclusive** keyword. If I use the keyword, **one node** of the cluster is chosen and all processes are launched there. However, I would like Slurm to distribute the ["sleeps"/steps] over the entire cluster.

So how does the keyword **exclusive** work ? According to the [Slurm documentaion](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html#OPT_exclusive%5B=user%7Cmcs%5D), the restriction to one node should not happen, since the keyword is used within a step-allocation.

[*I am new to Slurm*]

Comment: I don't think there is much to add to the SLURM documentation. It prevents the different `srun` steps from running on the same CPU cores (it is on be default on steps). I will note that this procedure is often not necessary; if the cluster allows node sharing then just using `--array` would be preferable to this approach.